# Post-apocalyptic cartoon from the early 2000's

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Around 2000 or 2001 there was a cartoon I used to watch and I can't remember the name of. Here's what I remember:

- The setting was post-apocalyptic but there was still high-technology, just a lot fewer people.
- The main character was a young man, typical "good guy looking for answers about the past", but at the point I stopped watching he was turning "evil" due to some sort of nanotech infection. He basically fell into a [grey goo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey_goo) river.
- I seem to recall a rivalry between the hero's father and some other guy, reminiscent of the rivalry between Superman's dad and General Zod.
- The nanotech in that cartoon wasn't identified *as* nanotech. It looked a lot like the Inque character from Batman Beyond.

The art style was rather minimalist, the character design was a bit "geometric", think "Clone Wars".

Finally, I used to watch this on French TV, which means it may actually have been produced before 2000.

Any idea what this might be?

Comment: Welcome to SFF! You have a very nice detailed description here but in case there is anything you missed, or it jogs your memory some more, it might be worth looking at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and [edit]ing anything else in. If you haven't already be sure to take the [tour]!

Comment: You mention it was on French TV. Was it in French? Or another language with French subtitles? Or do you think it had been in another language and dubbed into French?

Comment: It was dubbed in French, but based on the art style and theme it was definitely not a French production. It felt way too American, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably *Chris Colorado*, a French cartoon. This:

[image: The picture]

And it wasn't grey goo, but "dark torrent" in French.

Comment: That's it ! When I saw "Chris Colorado" in the notification for your comment it immediately felt right, didn't even have to check the picture, but it's a nice confirmation. Thank you ! I had no idea this was a French cartoon, I could have kept searching for a long time !

Comment: Glad to have been helpful